# Bitnami Redmine 4.1.1-5 login with default credentials fails

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I've installed a brand new Bitnami Redmine from this image under VirtualBox

```
bitnami-redmine-4.1.1-5-linux-debian-10-x86_64.ova
```

It works, I access the web homepage, but I am unable to login with default credentials. I printed my credentials with

```
cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials
```

which shows me what I need

```
Welcome to the Bitnami Redmine Stack

******************************************************************************
The default username and password is 'user' and '*******'.
******************************************************************************

You can also use this password to access the databases and any other component the stack includes.

Please refer to https://docs.bitnami.com/ for more details.
```

I copy/paste the values into login fields but login always fails. What am I doing wrong?

### Additional info

My pre-start.log:

```
sudo cat /opt/bitnami/var/log/pre-start.log

## 2020-10-28 13:33:50+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/010_set_system_user_password...
## 2020-10-28 13:33:50+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/020_hostname...
## 2020-10-28 13:33:50+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/030_swap_file...
650000+0 records in
650000+0 records out
665600000 bytes (666 MB, 635 MiB) copied, 1.62172 s, 410 MB/s
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 634.8 MiB (665595904 bytes)
no label, UUID=b4ec7182-58ad-428a-a447-414acfb3154e
## 2020-10-28 13:34:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/040_stack_etc...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:06+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/050_clean_pids...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:07+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/060_check_if_demo_machine...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:07+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/070_change_boot_log_permissions...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:07+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/080_prevent_incoming_connections...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:09+00:00 ## INFO ## 80 has been blocked
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## 443 has been blocked
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/090_get_default_passwords...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/100_regenerate_keys...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/110_configure_default_passwords...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/120_reenable_incoming_connections...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/130_resize_fs_partition...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/140_recreate_ssh_host_keys...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/150_welcome_message...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/160_welcome_message_reload...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:11+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/pre-start/170_enable_ufw...
```

My post-start.log:

```
## 2020-10-28 13:34:39+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/010_bitnami_agent_extra...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:39+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/020_bitnami_agent...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:39+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/030_update_ip...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:47+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/040_update_welcome_file...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:47+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/050_bitnami_credentials_file...
## 2020-10-28 13:34:47+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/060_start_gonit...
Starting gonit daemon
## 2020-10-28 13:34:47+00:00 ## INFO ## Running /opt/bitnami/var/init/post-start/070_clean_metadata...
```

Comment: You shouldn't get any error because that's the approach to get the password and log in to the application. Could you please use a different browser or an incognito window? Please ensure there was not any error during the boot process `sudo cat /opt/bitnami/var/log/pre-start.log; sudo cat /opt/bitnami/var/log/post-start.log`

Comment: Hi. I edited and expanded my ticket with these logs. I can't see any error.

Comment: From the logs you posted, everything seems fine. I don't know if you tried with a different browser or with an incognito window but we test this functionality in all the releases we do. If you launched the VM using the required memory (the one that is set by default), everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted an instant solution for easily create fully functional ticketing environment, but this Bitnami image couldn't give it to me.

I finally gave up and just downloaded the latest Turnkey Redmine image, which is the same environment, but a bit more. And it works for first try.

I know it's not the answer for my question, but a working solution.